# Theme my login remove username field

Tags: wordpress

I am using theme my login plugin and I do not want to use Username field when we register. Register with only email field.

appreciated in advance.

Comment: you will need to customize plugin register form for this.

Comment: Yes but how it works can you please explain me.

Comment: If you go to `theme-my-login\templates` , you will get file `ms-signup-user-form.php` , username field code is there , just comment that code and check on front site.

Comment: Thanks by its not working because this field is required field so we can not comment this part. when submit the form you got error that please add username.

Comment: Of course that condition of required field you will have to comment. That is basic. just hide field never work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer that we can remove that field using the jQuery and when click on register button we can put the email field value into username too.

And its work for me.

```
$('#wp-submit').click(function(){
        var emailID = $('#user_email').val();
        $('#user_login').val(emailID);
    })
```